# How to solve this logout error?

Tags: php, session, redirect

I am working on a pre-developed admin panel made with PHP by previous employees of my company. The problem I am getting that, if I left the admin panel opened for about 30 to 45 minutes and after that any menu link (say URL1) is clicked, it redirects to login page. And after re-logging in, the user is able to access all other menu links accept that URL1, when URL1 is clicked it redirects again to login page.

I have checked the code multiple times but haven't find any script which redirects user to login page after 30-45 minutes. In fact I have changed all login page redirection to logout page redirection. Below is my logout page code. Sometimes session and cookies doesn't get clear after executing logout.php page.

VPS has reverse caching software enabled in it, is it the problem?

Here is the logout.php code:

```
<?php
session_start();

unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
unset($_SESSION['user_email']);
unset($_SESSION['full_name']);
unset($_SESSION['user_level']);
session_unset(); 
session_destroy();

// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
        header("Location: login.php");
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: seems like a redirection issue, probably need more issues about how URI redirection is handled in relation to logging. Are you using a popular CMS?

Comment: it is simple redirection after usual authentication check, I am not using any popular CMS. It is custom CMS.

Comment: when the session expires and you are redirected to the login, is "URL 1" as you are calling, saved as a query string/post variable for redirection after login?

Comment: No there is no query string.. it is clean url

Comment: It's difficult for me to take a guess at your problem. I'd have to see more of your code, but it really does sound like an issue with caching and the way your cms handles login redirection (which you already know). Sorry i can't be of more help.

Comment: For reference you dont need to unset single sessions simply running `session_destroy()` will remove all current session data

Comment: Thanks for your effort :)

Comment: @PrateekAnand When it redirects to the login page, is a new session started with new data?

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius I have tried all those, but it din't work

Comment: @KenziieeFlavius When it redirects to login page, all the sessions are cleared.

Comment: @PrateekAnand I meant on the login page itself after the redirect and clears from the logout page, i think we need to see more code to find the problem :/